# Client-server data synchronization data structure in android?

Tags: java, android, data-structures

My project has multiple android devices connected to each other via bluetooth. One android device acts as a server and rest of them as clients. Each client sends a message to the server and the server forwards the message to rest of the connected clients.

Now I want to synchronize a data list among all the connected devices. Since there is already a channel open between the devices, I would like to use it to send synchronization events/data so that all the devices are in sync. The sync data list will mostly have the list of devices connected, their status, the list of events which they are interested. But I don't what data structure would be best to store such a data.

The data list will be shared at the beginning when the connections are setup and also when there is any update on any of the fields.

For example:

The data list must have the below details:

```
Device - Server
Status - Connected
Events - eventA, eventB, eventC

Device - Client1
Status - Connected
Events - eventA, eventB

Device - Client2
Status - Connected
Events - eventB, eventC

Device - Client3
Status - Connected
Events - eventA, eventB
```

What is the best way to store these data in android? Also this has to be serializable so that it can be sent via bluetooth.

Comment: In in instance of a class with menbers Device, Status and Events. Then the list contains those instances. For every client one.

Comment: After that you have to decide how you want to transfer the data of every instance in the list to a client. That is up to you. You will send only text for that i suppose. If you can send a message the you can send that list text as message too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is it possible to serialize a class and send via bluetooth?

Comment: If your class would be serializable i dont know. Depends on the structure. Keep it simple. But if you can serialize it you have just text. And that text you can send as message as you do now. But what is so difficult to convert data like `Device - Client2
Status - Connected
Events - eventB, eventC` to some text lines? Or xml lines? Or whatever you want.